Flask, Cloudetype
Real-time chat seems to work when running in pycharm, but it doesn't work well when deployed through cloudetype.
github
---------app.py----------
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        session['room'] = 'default_room'
        return redirect(url_for('chat'))
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    username = session.get('username')
    if not username:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('chat.html', username=username, room=session['room'])

@socketio.on('join', namespace='/chat')
def join(message):
    username = message['username']
    room = message['room']
    join_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': username + ' has joined the room.'}, room=room)

@socketio.on('message', namespace='/chat')
def message(message):
    emit('message', {'msg': message['username'] + ': ' + message['msg']}, room=message['room'])

@socketio.on('leave', namespace='/chat')
def leave(message):
    username = message['username']
    room = message['room']
    leave_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': username + ' has left the room.'}, room=room)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)

----------index.html--------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Welcome to GroupChat</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enter Chat</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

-----chat.html----------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Chat Room</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/chat');

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('join', {'username': '{{ username }}', 'room': '{{ room }}'});
            });

            $('form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let user_input = $('#user_input').val();
                socket.emit('message', {'msg': user_input, 'username': '{{ username }}', 'room': '{{ room }}'});
                $('#user_input').val('');
            });

            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.msg));
            });

            socket.on('status', function(data) {
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.msg));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Chat Room</h2>
        <ul id="messages" class="list-unstyled"></ul>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="user_input" placeholder="Type your message here..." class="form-control" required>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

-------------cloudtype setting---
this is setting image in cloudtype
enter image description here
afa
af
asdaf
s
fw
fw
de
afd
a
d

You don't seem to be following the deployment documentation here. I suggest you try the --threads option for gunicorn, as shown in the page I linked.
